# Vertical (or block) selection in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, selection, codemirror

Is there a way to do a vertical selection in codemirror as you do in the ace editor by pressing alt and dragging?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codemirror 4.2 now includes vertical selection when holding the alt key while dragging to select text. Try it on any of the demos: http://codemirror.net/

Comment: Very nice! Thanks Stephen

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. See https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/778 for some related discussion.